# How do I justify the use of multiple JS files for view specific procedures

Tags: javascript, architecture

Basically, we have a massive `core.js` file with **lots** of jQuery calls that have no structure whatsoever. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on({
        change: function() {
            // some code specific to 1 view
        }
    },
    "#some-id-name-that-may-exist-in-multiple-views" // like "bank-box"
});

// This code isn't even inside a closure, so it get's executed in all views but '.metadata' only exist in one, braking the whole system.
checkProgress($.parseJSON($('.metadata').text()));
```

Now, as the comment says, it has happened before that a whole section of the system breaks because of a JS error that usually happens due to the share of JS code. (Ironically, thanks to the sharing of said code, Continuous Integration caught it because of the only 1% of the code that's tested)

How do I justify the usage of separate JS files that holds view-specific logic, instead of a massive `core.js` that exist because of the "the browser would cache all of the JS on the first load" argument. Any resources or links are welcome.

On the other hand, maybe multiple files is an incorrect approach and we need to have 1 `core.js` file, but the code should be in a different way so that it doesn't conflict like it does right now. If this is the case, then how.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check for the existence of those elements, that you are working on. You could rewrite your this code like this:

```
if( $(".metadata").length ){
  checkProgress($.parseJSON($('.metadata').text()));
}// if $(".metadata").length
```

Comment: However, a code that's structured like this doesn't have a good readability. You'd practically have to guess where that call is supposed to run on.